# Is there any use case, where String.lowercased().contains will behave differently than String.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains?

Tags: ios, swift

I try to test the following code under different Locale settings

```
let text = "total sdfs"
let text1 = "Total 张"
let text2 = "TOTAL لطيف"
let text3 = "total :"
let text4 = "ToTaL : "

text.lowercased().contains("total".lowercased())
text1.lowercased().contains("张".lowercased())
text2.lowercased().contains("لطيف".lowercased())
text3.lowercased().contains("total".lowercased())
text4.lowercased().contains("total".lowercased())

text.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains("total")
text1.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains("张")
text2.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains("لطيف")
text3.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains("total")
text4.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains("total")
```

However, all of them behave same under different system Locale settings.

I was wondering, is there any good example, where where `String.lowercased().contains` will behave differently than `String.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains`?

Or, those 2 code are just equivalent?

Comment: `print("ß".lowercased().contains("ss".lowercased()))` vs `print("ß".localizedCaseInsensitiveContains("ss"))` gives different outputs in Playground. It's a german character (see Eszett)

Comment: Thanks for this helpful tips. May I know, from native German users perspective, which is the correct behavior, if I were to provide a case insensitive search feature?

Comment: I'm not German, but I know that exception (I don't know others though). Since it's "the same" I'd go that it should return "true", so use `localizedCaseInsensitiveContains()`.

Comment: And localizedCaseInsensitiveContains makes for more readable code imo if that’s relevant

Comment: localizedCaseInsensitiveContains Is the recommended approach

Comment: In some languages there are different, equivalent representations of the same text. An Eszett is a good example. An Eszett is equivalent to a double `s`. You can spell Groß, the German word for large, as `Groß` or `Gross`. Does `Groß` contain an `ss`? It contains an Eszett, which is equivalent to a double `s`, so yes (sort of)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that I could observe a different behavior from the language Turkish.

In below code, `text5.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains("Şemsİye")` returns false, but comparing it to `text6.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains("çarŞamba")` it should have returned true.

```
let text5 = "Siyah şemsiye."
let text6 = "Çarşamba çarşafa dolanır."

text5.lowercased().contains("şemsiye".lowercased()) // true
text5.lowercased().contains("şemsİye".lowercased()) // false

text6.lowercased().contains("çarşamba".lowercased()) // true
text6.lowercased().contains("Çarsamba".lowercased()) // false

text5.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains("şemsiye") // true
text5.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains("Şemsiye") // true
text5.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains("Şemsİye") // false

text6.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains("çarşamba") // true
text6.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains("Çarşamba") // true
text6.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains("çarŞamba") // true
```

The character "İ" is the Turkish capital of "i". The difference seems unique to this character because "ö", "ü" seems to be working like the character "ç".

```
let i = "i"
let ı = "ı"
let İ = "İ"
let I = "I"

i.capitalized // "I"
ı.capitalized // "I"
İ.lowercased() // "i̇"
İ.localizedLowercase // "i̇" (it has two dots, but in Turkish it should be "i" with one dot.
I.lowercased() // "i"
```